# Java ignores the string

Tags: java, string, input

I'm new to programming and this problem always faces me 
When I run the program Java ignores a string input inside an if
What did I do wrong?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class JavaApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("------ FEEDBACK/COMPLAINT ------\n"
                + "-------------------------------------\n"
                + "| 1: Submit Feedback |\n"
                + "| 2: Submit Complaint |\n"
                + "| 3: Previous Menu |\n"
                + "-----------------------------------\n"
                + "> Please enter the choice: ");
        int feedorcomw = input.nextInt();

        if (feedorcomw == 1) {
            String name;
            System.out.print("> Enter your name (first and last): ");
            name = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.print("> Enter your mobile (##-###-####): ");
            int num = input.nextInt();

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: what type of the error are you getting?

Comment: Maybe this answers your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo-methods

Comment: @and your edit doesn't make much sense - why make a minimal complete example into one that isn't instead of just fixing the formatting?

Answer (score 1):

you are ommitting the fact that  **Scanner#nextInt** method does not consume the last newline character of your input, and thus that newline is consumed in the next call to **Scanner#nextLine**

try adding a  `input.nextLine();` after that and everything will work fine

## Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("------ FEEDBACK/COMPLAINT ------\n"
            + "-------------------------------------\n"
            + "| 1: Submit Feedback |\n"
            + "| 2: Submit Complaint |\n"
            + "| 3: Previous Menu |\n"
            + "-----------------------------------\n"
            + "> Please enter the choice: ");
    int feedorcomw = input.nextInt();

    input.nextLine();
    if (feedorcomw == 1) {
        String name;
        System.out.print("> Enter your name (first and last): ");
        name = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.print("> Enter your mobile (##-###-####): ");
        int num = input.nextInt();

    }

}
```